# PHP_Mongo Driver for PHP 5.3.8 and WAMP 2.2

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using WAMP server 2.2. and PHP 5.3.8. I need to connect to MongoDB
from PHP. Can anyone please tell me, which PHP_mongo db is suitable of the drivers available in the following link 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

I believe WAMP is compiled using VC9, thread safe, 32bit.

The corresponding DLL file (inside one of the .zip archives) would be: php_mongo-1.4.5-5.3-vc9.dll